# Contract source code on Goerli testnet

Tags: etherscan, goerli

I want to compare my code of a contract I deployed on testnet to an already deployed contract on Eth mainnet.

Now mainnet etherscan shows contract source code but on goerli testnet I can't see the source code for the contract it asks to decrypt but does so incorrectly.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you deployed the contract on testnet... Dont you already have the source code for it?

Comment: I have the code I deployed but the contract I want to measure with has several codes in a single file combined. Namely Uniswap interfaces and ERC20 setup functions. So I am trying to see if I have followed every function or not. 

I am learning so want to make sure that the contract I am trying to make (the one that is on the mainnet) is similar to it with all the functions of ERC20 and Uniswap exactly the same.

Would appreciate your help!

Comment: Your question is very confusing. If you deployed a contract to testnet, it means you already have a source code for it. Why are you trying to compare contracts? Are you trying to get the Uniswap source code?

Answer (score 0):

you can verify the contract if you have the source code from Ethereum on goerli, right? At least this will prove if the code is the same or not